# How to use comparison operator in Javascript for two input values

Tags: javascript

I want to compare the two input values, just try in javascript, but it's not working fine.  I'm using the following code

```
function check_closing()
{
var opening = $('#opening').val();
var closing = $('#closing').val();
if(opening > closing)
{
    alert('Opening is greater than Closing. Please enter the correct value');
    $('#closing').val('');
}
}
```

if the opening value input = 8541, closing value like = 8241 it's work fine, but if the closing is 954 it's not working. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the strings to integers before comparison:

```
function check_closing()
{
    var opening = $('#opening').val();
    var closing = $('#closing').val();
    if(parseInt(opening) > parseInt(closing))
    {
        alert('Opening is greater than Closing. Please enter the correct value');
        $('#closing').val('');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're comparing the strings instead of integers, so you need to convert the strings to integers. Since as strings, '8541' > '8241'

```
>>>'8541' > '8241'
true
>>>'954' > '8241'
true

>>>8541 > 8241
true
>>>954 > 8241
false
```

So you want:

```
function check_closing()
{
    var opening = parseInt($('#opening').val());
    var closing = parseInt($('#closing').val());
    if(opening > closing)
    {
        alert('Opening is greater than Closing. Please enter the correct value');
        $('#closing').val('');
    }
}
```

To add more to why exactly this happened, in case you're interested: Strings are compared character by character, iirc. So the '9' is greater than the '8' but the '8241' is less than '8541' because '2' is less than '5'.

Comment: You mean `'954' > '8241'`

Comment: *"Since as strings, '8541' > '8241'..."* As numbers, too.

Comment: Yeah, whoops. Updating now. Both the comments meant that. I didn't get it originally. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

The values of `input` elements are always strings. To compare them as numbers, you must convert them to numbers. You can do that with:

- `parseInt` if they're whole numbers and you want to specify the number base and stop parsing at the first non-numeric character

  Example:

  ```
  var opening = parseInt($('#opening').val(), 10);
  // This is the number base, usually 10 ---^^^^
  ```
- `parseFloat` if they're decimal fractional numbers

  Example:

  ```
  var opening = parseFloat($('#opening').val()); // Always base 10
  ```
- The `+` if you want JavaScript to guess the number base, and give you `NaN` if there's a non-numeric character

  Example:

  ```
  var opening = +$('#opening').val();
  //            ^---- it's hiding here
  ```

...and a few others.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you you need to convert the `strings` into `integers`

```
function check_closing(){
    var opening = parseInt($('#opening').val(), 10);
    var closing = parseInt($('#closing').val(), 10);
    if(opening > closing){
        alert('Opening is greater than Closing. Please enter the correct value');
        $('#closing').val('');
    }
}
```